# How to cancel ACU upgrade

Tags: supreme-commander

I have bought a insanely expensive upgrade (teleporter) by accident. It costs 1.5M energy, and I cannot afford it. However, I can't cancel the upgrade either.

This makes the only way to save my economy to pause the upgrade and do not use my ACU until the end of the game.

Does anyone have an idea how to cancel the upgrade thus unblock the ACU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also cancel by selecting the commander and ordering it to **(S)top** (the red fist icon).

Answer (score 2):

After you select the ACU, press escape.